# ExtJS DataView equivalent for Dojo?

Tags: extjs, dojo, widget, dataview

Is there an equivalent widget in Dojo's arsenal that's similar to the grid-style view that ExtJS's DataView provides?

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/view/data-view.html

I know that I could just use both Dojo and ExtJS, but I'd really like to stick with just Dojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about [dojox.image.thumbnailPicker](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/image/ThumbnailPicker.html).. perhaps this is what you need..

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for - I need drag-and-drop reordering and the images aren't necessarily thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

There is now [dGrid](http://dgrid.io/).

This allows for gallery style presentation as well as drag and drop. I haven't personally used this in conjunction but the functionality is implemented through mixins, which means that they should both be supported.

There is an example of a gallery style view here:

http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/demos/multiview/